changing the icon of windows app using Tycho not working
<launcher name="idealized">
      <linux icon="icons/linux.xpm"/>
      <macosx icon="icons/macos.icns"/>
      <win useIco="true">
         <ico path="icons/windows.ico"/>
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

After mvn clean verify it gives following error:
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-publisher:4.0.8:publish-products (default-publish-products) @ idealized-product ---
[IconExe] Error - 7 original icon(s) not replaced in C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\p2.brandingIron3874598256860483952\launcher.exe:
        - 48x48, 8 bits, 3752 byte(s) @ 241680
        - 32x32, 8 bits, 2216 byte(s) @ 245432
        - 16x16, 8 bits, 1384 byte(s) @ 247648
        - 48x48, 32 bits, 9640 byte(s) @ 249032
        - 32x32, 32 bits, 4264 byte(s) @ 258672
        - 16x16, 32 bits, 1128 byte(s) @ 262936
        - 256x256, 32 bits, 270376 byte(s) @ 264064
[IconExe] For more details, see https://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.p2.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.eclipse/src/org/eclipse/pde/internal/swt/tools/IconExe.java    

When build get complete it shows large view icon correct which I have set and give issue on small and medium icons view, and initially the app icon that shows up in task bar also appears wrong (Eclpise Icon appears which I want to change) and after loading and opening of app it becomes my desired icon.
small-icon-view
medium_icon_view
large_icon_view
initial_wrong_error_during_loading
after_loading_icon

The images in an .ico file can be in different bit depths, but for an Eclipse application, the images must be in 32 bits (8 bits each for the three colors and 8 bits for the alpha channel) and except for the 256x256 images in 8 bits (256 colors). Alternatively, you can provide the images individually as PNG images.

Dear @howlger, I have replaced all my images in org.idealized.customization/icons with your default icons. And also replaced my own icon in product/icons windows.ico. But as mentioned above it is not replacing the launcher exe file image successfully. If there is any method which I can follow to counter this bits problem let me know coz I have edited all images with 32 bits property but its not working.

It worked with my product/icons/windows.ico but not with your customized .ico file, right? The images contained in the .ico file must be in special formats (see my first comment): 32 bit or 256 slot palette, both not compressed. Compressed or other formats could be the reason for your issue. Check the size of your .ico file, if it is smaller, then that is probably the problem. When using Gimp, for exporting do not use the default settings but the mentioned formats only. If this does not work, share your .ico file.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aLVJ_Bv3y4zz_n2YHYMd9TDehNoqZl10?usp=drive_link .... I have uploaded my folders in it with replaced images / icons you can see it.

Yes it worked fine with your windows.ico file. But not with mine, sorry I am not getting the concept of different images when there is only 1 ico file, how there are multiple images inside single windows.ico file of different bits?

The .icn file is a container for multiple images. So technically, you can have different icons for different sizes. When using Gimp, each image is in a separate layer. Does the following .icn file work for you? https://file.io/te2XvlGJYiaf, https://file.io/ZBLpgPwTTHDi or https://file.io/KOItvdH0jrCa (same file uploaded three times since they will be deleted after downloading).

Dear @howlger, first two links ico files were working fine for small and medium icon view. 3rd file is working fine for every view. I am very thankful to you for this help. Can you please let me know how you fixed it so I can learn as well.

Which tool do you want to use to create the .ico file? I used Gimp where the images are on separate layers. So you must make sure that each layer has the right size. In the File > Export... dialog, you can choose the bpp for each layer. The RedKetchup online icon editor or other icon editors should work too as long as they support to choose the required formats for the 7 images. You might start by opening a working .ico file and then replace the images one by one.

Dear @howlger, how can I generate bin file(application file) for Linux of IDEalized?

Unfortunately I have no experience with .bin installation files on Linux, only some experience with .rpm files.

@howlger, so in tar.gz for Linux produced by Idealized doesn't contain IDE application runnable file?

The .tar.gz file for Linux should contain the executable files idealized and idealizedc (to run the IDE use the first; the latter is for execution headless, on the command line, hence the suffix c).

@howlger, so how can I get the IDEalized app installer for linux as it was done for windows using nsis.? Like if I have to share my customized app to different users to install on their PC how that linux build can be shared?

I have no experience with this. It depends on which installer you want to use. Here is the one for Flatpak, which I have not tried myself, but know from others that it works: https://github.com/flathub/org.eclipse.Java

@howlger, I have tried to make app install using debian for linux it is working fine but there is issue related to app launching as it gives error about workspace. Problem is that it is fetching local PC folder paths as it is build within the IDEalized app and when it will be installed on other pc definitely there will be no same path of workspace and other things. Similar kind of issue I found for Windows NSIS installation as during extracting it shows local PC folder paths but it should be not visible as it is formed with aim to share with different users... How these things can be resolved?

What do you mean by "fetching local PC folder paths"? Which path? Please give an example. For multi-user installation see https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html
